# PHP Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php

> PHP Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/bazaraz1/public_html/result.php on line 371

Пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться с этой проблемой.

Comment: @Visman некроф....))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/bazaraz1/public_html/result.php on line 371**

Говорит о том, что пустое значение вернул запрос, нету результата, есть только ошибка, проверяйте сам запрос, тоесть **mysql_query**, а лучше всего покажите часть кода, строчки 368-372.

Comment: Uvajaemiy Andrey, smojete mne napisat Vashu email?

Comment: arsh-andrej@yandex.ru